# How to modify shell to show git branch one is in, if applicable

Tags: git, shell

Right now, my shell is set to display `export PS1="\t \w $ "`

Is there any way make prompt dynamic, always reevaluating it's current location and format to the following rules:

**1. When inside directory that contains `git` repo, it changes to include branch i am on**

```
19:42:07 (dev) ~ $ 

19:42:07 (release) ~ $
```

**1.1 Can branch be shown in different color then the rest of the prompt?**

**2. When outside of the directory that contains `git` repo, it stays as is**

```
19:42:07 ~ $
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Git distribution contains a `contrib/completion/git-completion.bash` file which does this, and much more besides. The file itself contains installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

In case the git-completion.bash solution isn't feasible (eg: no privileges to install git-completion, etc), you can manually add the following function to the .bashrc,

```
function parse_git_branch {
      git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
```

and call that function from the command to format PS1. I use the following:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h: \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[37m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[32m\] \$\[\e[0m\] '
```

which results in

[image]

where `ParVal` is the name of the branch I'm in.